# Using the preposition "like" in a sentence

Tags: expressions, prepositions

Can I say: "You can apply this method to like types of problems". If not, why?

Comment: There's an adjective you have there. Like types = similar sorts. Unlike = different. But the sentence is good, meaning all problems of this type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

***Like*** can be an adjective:

> ***[like](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/like)***
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1. attributive (of a person or thing) having similar qualities or characteristics to another person or thing.
>      *‘I responded in like manner’*
>      *‘the grouping of children of like ability together’*

However, depending on your audience, I would probably be inclined to use ***similar*** instead, just because I think it's more common and less (potentially) confusing.

Comment: I would use "similar" in this case, too. I would even argue that this meaning of "like" is becoming obsolete.